# get networkx Digraph control flow graph traversal

Tags: networkx

I start using networkx framework (python) for graphs and it seems lacking a basic topological traversal (control flow graph)function for directed graph (Digraph). 
For example, I have the next graph:

[image]

and I would like to traverse the graph in a way that node with id 195 will not be visited until all its predecessors (nodes 43 and 45 were visited). bfs and dfs doesn't garenty it.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail and in particular give an example of the sort of input you would want this function to have and what its output would be?